# mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given -
Face this error using the below query for nested filtration in eloquent using with.

```
$columns = Column::with(['cards', function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query) {
            if (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] != '') {
                $query->where('status', trim($_GET['status']));
            }
            })
            ->where(function ($query) {
            if (isset($_GET['date']) && $_GET['date'] != '') {
                $query->where('created_at', trim($_GET['date']));
            }
            });
    }])->get();
```

Comment: `mb_strpos()` doesn't appear in the code you've posted, so we don't know where this error is occurring.  The message is clear, though. You're sending it an object and it wants a string. You should be able to sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to query on 'cards' relations ? If yes, you can try this query

```
$columns = Column::with(['cards' => function ($query) {
```

Comment: Your query is passing the callback to second array, have you tried to pass the callback as array value of 'cards' ?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/mb-strpos-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given-2?page=1&replyId=767306

Can you please see this I have discuss in detail about this issue.